# Jenkins Pipeline give User Input to run specific testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, gradle, testng

I'm using gradle with selenium (Java) Testng to automate my test cases and choose Jenkins to build the scripts.

I have many **testng.xml** files in my workspace under **src/test/resources** --> **ACE_Regression** (package)

My **build.gradle** looks like this

```
buildscript 
{

ext

 {

testNgVersion = "6.14.3"

    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {

    jcenter()

     mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {

    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation "org.testng:testng:$testNgVersion"

    compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.23'

    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.14.0'

    compile group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports', version: '3.0.6'

    compile group: 'com.relevantcodes', name: 'extentreports', version: '2.41.2'

    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.0.0'

    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.0.0'

    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'

    compile group: 'ru.yandex.qatools.ashot', name: 'ashot', version: '1.5.2'

    testCompile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.0.0'

    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'

  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.12.1'

  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.12.1'  

}



test {

useTestNG() 

{

suites "src/test/resources/ACE_Regression/Acelogin.xml"

suites "src/test/resources/ACE_Regression/CLAs.xml"

    }
}
```

Right now i use "**gradlew test**" to run my tests from jenkins.

I want to give input from jenkins to run only CLAs.xml file. Like this i have many XML files avaliable . I want to parameterize the job to pick only required testng files and run.

Can someone help me how to setup this test task in build.gradle file and jenkins

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try passing system property along with gradle task `gradlew test -DXmlName="yourxml"` and then access the system property in build.gradle to do the job

Answer (score 0):

Modify the useTestNG() in your **build.grade** . It should accept one dynamic parameter e.g. xmlName.

```
test {

    useTestNG() 
        {
           suites "src/test/resources/ACE_Regression/${xmlName}.xml"
        }
    }
```

Pass the xmlName using -P option in your gradle invocation block. i.e. `gradlew test -PxmlName=CLAs` , it should work.

To make it more dynamic, *Make your jenkins build parameterized*.  Create a choice parameter by the name of **testSuites** and add all the possible xml file names in it. 
Then pass this choice parameter to the gradle invocation command block i.e. `gradle test -PxmlName=${testSuites}`

Comment: what if I have to pass multiple values from jenkins ? Like different test suites to execute ...... which means i have to dynamically add another line under  useTestNG ()  { suites "src/test/resources/ACE_Regression/${xmlName1}.xml"   suites "src/test/resources/ACE_Regression/${xmlName2}.xml" }}

Comment: Make your build parameterized. Add *choice parameter*, populate the choices with possible values of testSuite file names using , and new line separator. Use the choice parameter name in your executable command.